Movie in which a man sees himself as dead in a mirror in the end
I'm looking for an american movie, probably from the fifties or sixties. If I remember correctly, it's a collection of scary stories, one I remember specifically:
A man is in a car crash, but wanders off unharmed. He starts walking home, and people act weird around him. At the end of his story, he finally sees himself in the mirror (might have been a mirror in a table) and sees that he's a walking corpse.
I think all people in the different stories are gathered together and in the end they realize they are all dead, don't remember if they're supposed to be in a heaven/hell-like place or something else.
Does anyone recognize this movie?
Edit: I googled around a bit and found this gif, from the 1988 movie Dead Heat which has a very similar scene, this is however not the movie I'm looking for: 

Also, the framing device sounds very similar to the plot of the 1945 movie Dead of Night however none of the stories really sound like the one I'm looking for.

This sounds very much like a portion of the portmanteau horror film Tales From the Crypt (1972).
The portion I am thinking of is called Reflection of Death.
The wikipedia plot description explains:

Carl Maitland (Ian Hendry) abandons his family to be with Susan Blake
  (Angela Grant). After they drive off together, they are involved in a
  car accident. He wakes up in the wrecked car and attempts to
  hitch-hike home, but no one will stop for him. Arriving at his house,
  he sees his wife (Susan Denny) with another man.
He knocks on the door, but she screams and slams the door. He then
  goes to see Susan to find out that she is blind from the accident. She
  says that Carl died two years ago from the crash. Looking in a
  reflective tabletop he sees he has the face of a corpse. Carl then
  wakes up and finds out that it was a dream but the moment he does, the
  crash occurs as it did before.

The scene that you describe is shown at about 1'10" in this trailer:




This must be it! :D I want to remember it as being black and white, but that's probably just my memory playing tricks on me. Everything with the strangers getting visions about how they died sounds correct. Thanks for your answer!

When you mentioned a collection of stories and the time I would be lead to belive it may be an episode from the Twilight Zone. 
Cant find exact episode at the moment. 

I'm pretty sure what I saw was a movie, but I wouldn't doubt there's an episode with a similar plot and theme :)
